# Appcelerator's `Titanium.UI.openFileChooserDialog` Fails in TideSDK

Tags: javascript, macos, titanium, tidesdk

On OSX, I have an old [Appcelerator Titanium](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium) app, that I want to migrate it to the new [TideSDK platform](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK).

Now, I can:

- download and install TideSDK (https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/downloads -> *TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-osx-x86-64.dmg* and *TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-osx-x86-64.zip*)
- open my current appcelerator project with TideSDK
- and i) Launch The App and ii) Package With Runtime (then launch)

But an invocation to `Titanium.UI.openFileChooserDialog(parseCsvFile,options);` doesn't do anything. Below is what the current code looks like. How can I get a Dialog FileChooser invoked in TideSDK ?

```
function selectFile() {
  var options = {
    multiple    : false,
    title   : "Open file",
    types   : ['csv', 'txt'],
    typesDescription  : "CSV files",
    path    : Titanium.Filesystem.getUserDirectory()
  }

  Titanium.UI.openFileChooserDialog(parseCsvFile,options);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [correct command](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI.UserWindow-method-openFileChooserDialog) needs to happen from within a window, like this:

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.openFileChooserDialog(function(e) {
    // Do stuff after the user has closed the dialog here
    ...

}, { // Specify options
    multiple: false,
    title   : "Open file",
    types   : ['csv', 'txt'],
    path    : Ti.Filesystem.getUserDirectory()
});
```